# Playing GIFs and videos in VideoView using Glide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide, android-videoview

I'm currently using the [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images into my `ImageView`s, but now I need to be able to load external GIFs and videos.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How can I use `VideoView` to load external GIFs and videos using Glide? Do I even need Glide in this instance?

Comment: Did u get an answer ? Even I need to do this part in my app. Did you found it ? If so, please share your answer here or any link that would be helpful.

Comment: Glide supports gif loading, u can use `asGif()` to play gif image in `ImageView`. But Glide does not support video playing, cause it just an image loading library as the owner said.